# WP(4.7) Gallery Not Working with Visual Composer 5.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I can not add images to WP posts or see images in the thumbnail gallery mode I have update WordPress to version 4.7 and my theme and all plug-in’s including Visual Composer 5.1. None of this has helped. If I deactivate Visual Composer the media gallery works but my site does not. If I look in the browser console I get

> “Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error) /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php“

I have replaced this file it did not help. I have deleted and reinstalled Visual Composer, I have reinstalled WP. I’m not a WP wizard and I will feel like I’m drowning here.

Comment: just replace your wp-admin and wp-include folder

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not work.

Comment: Visual composer is compitible?

Comment: active another theme and check